# Why can't I get my System E-mail working in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to set up a Gmail system Email account, however I keep getting an error. I set it up on my local host instance's system e-mail account exactly how my co-worker set his up, but I keep getting this error and he does not on his system. I had my co-worker send me the related DLL file, but I still got the same error:

[image]

I am working with 2019 R2.

EDIT: Here is the trace for the error as requested:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the stack trace to the question?

Comment: I have added the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered that same error before, and in my case it was a firewall issue. The Port 587 was not allowed. Can you try to use telnet to check the connection? If you don't want to install telnet, you can try to check the connection using Powershell, it should be something like this:

```
test-netconnection -computername smtp.gmail.com -Port 587
```